# Calling onActivityResult() after re-creating Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

There is Activity A. From this activity I call startActivityForResult() for Gallery. When Gallery activity is opening, activity A was killed (because device hasn't enough memory). After that we choose image and move to activity A, but onActivityResult() method didn't call.

How can I resolve this situation?

Comment: from my experience you can't:(

Comment: What should be happening if 'A' was killed is that onCreate() runs followed by onActivityResult(). Does your code work if 'A' does not die? It may help if you show the code you use start the Gallery intent and the code you use when it returns.

Comment: @NigelK, I am running into same issue. my code work if A does not dia. And yes 'A' was onCreate() running followed by onActivityResult() in my case